# Jquery select by form id

Tags: jquery

I have a code below. If have one form in the page its work fine but if i want to use more form i need to define what to do if form1 submit or and if form2 submit. How can i do this? I try some way but don't work.

```
$(function() {

$("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                message: message
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function() {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                    .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function() {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                    .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
        })
    },
    filter: function() {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    },
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
```

});

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: I tryed to get the form id and simply choose with one if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the question but if you are asking how to catch the submission of the forms you would use :

```
$('#form1').submit(function {
    $($(this).find("input,textarea")).jqBootstrapValidation({
    preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
    // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM
        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var message = $("textarea#message").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
    // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
    [...]
})
```

and

```
$('#form2').submit(function {
    [...code...]
})
```

If you could clarify what exactly you want to do we might give you a better answer.

Comment: Yes this is what i want but i try some way to insert this but won't work. :/

Comment: I checked. Now work but the realtime error check not.
I need catch after this: submitSuccess: function($form, event) {

Comment: Can i get the actual form by id or name below this line? "submitSuccess: function($form, event) {"
If yes than one simple if can help.

Comment: Do you get any value for the form variable in the form. You can try changing the function to function(form, event){} and then use $(form) in the function. Another option is to create a variable between those two lines $('#form1').submit(function {
    $($(this).find("input,textarea")).jqBootstrapValidation({. For example var currentForm = this; and then use $(currentForm) in the submitSuccess